# Scope of callback function in "new" on JS object literal

Tags: javascript, scope, literals

In this code, the callback function receives the scope of the new `Thing` object (as the commend shows, `Thing` is logged.) Use of an arrow function causes it to log the window object.

I'd like to be able to access the scope of the `literal` object in that callback function, ideally without referring to it from the global object. Is there some way to do this?

```
function Thing(fun){
    this.funThing = fun
}

let literal = {
    thing: new Thing(function(){
        console.log(this)
    })
}

literal.thing.funThing() // Thing {funThing: ƒ}
```

Comment: I've made some edits, hopefully that should clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a getter instead, main difference here would be that upon each access the thing would be recreated, but well, that you could overcome in a different way ;)

And yes, I changed it to an arrow function here, but I could have bound the callback function as well

```js
function Thing(fun){
    this.funThing = fun
}

let literal = {
    get thing() {
      return new Thing(() => {
        console.log(this)
      });
    }
}

literal.thing.funThing()
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution of lcepickle works fine. Another way is to bind the callback function with the literal object, but in this case you have to define it before calling `new Thing` constructor. So, you can add the `thing` attribute after the definition of literal object:

```
function Thing(fun){
    this.funThing = fun
}

let literal = { }
literal.thing = new Thing(function(){
    console.log(this)
}.bind(literal))

literal.thing.funThing()
```

Comment: It might be argued that this is referring to `literal` from the global object, but this does seem like a classic use case for `.bind`

Comment: @GregoryTippett See I don't get it, this answer exactly does what you didn't want to do, and still it's marked as an answer. Any way I can improve my answer to make that more satisfying for you?

Comment: @Icepickle, you are correct. This solution is ultimately more sensible in terms of my actual code, which is why I clicked it, but your solution does answer my question more accurately in the terms that it was framed.

Answer (score -1):

You could bind the anonymous callback function to the scope of the `literal` object.

```js
function Thing(fun){
    this.funThing = fun
}

literal = {
    thing: new Thing(function(){
        console.log(this)
    }.bind(this.literal))
}

literal.thing.funThing()
```